# Angular 4 - delete function to delete number of rows selected in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table with rows and checkboxes. One main checkbox in header along with multiple checkboxes for every row. Now looking for function that will delete the number of rows from table with a delete button. challenge is it should delete all rows if i select table top check box which selects all rows and it should be able to delete single row as well if i click on single row. i have given code and plunkr example as well below that have used in my application to give better idea about row selection.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7l4AltdWfLGdLaXgF4vl?p=info

```
@Component({
      select
or: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Hello Angular2</h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Diameter</th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="all" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let size of sizes ; let i = index">
                    <td class="text-right">{{i + 1}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{size.size}}</td>
                    <td>{{size.diameter}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}" [(ngModel)]="size.state"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      sizes: any[] = [
        { 'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km' },
        { 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' },
{ 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' }
      ];

      checkAll(ev) {
        this.sizes.forEach(x => x.state = ev.target.checked)
      }

      isAllChecked() {
        return this.sizes.every(_ => _.state);
      }
    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ App ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: did you try to create a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this https://plnkr.co/edit/SiKo9H4RCn1ebqTosGZt?p=info

```js
check(size) {
    size.state = !size.state;
}
  
delete() {
    this.sizes.forEach(x => {
      if(x.state) { alert(x.size); }
    });
}
```

```html
<td class="text-center">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}"
  [(ngModel)]="size.state" (click)="check(size)"/>
</td>
...
<button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
...
```